# How can we underline n-th letter in angular ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a requirement in my project.
I am having titles loaded in a scope variable from http call :

```
 $scope.titleObject = [{
     "title": "Title1",
     "underlinekey": "t" }, {
     "title": "Sub-Heading",
     "underlinekey": "u" }, {
     "title": "Heading text",
     "underlinekey": "a" }, {
     "title": "Some Title",
     "underlinekey": "o" }, {
     "title": "More Title",
     "underlinekey": "r" }];
```

Now I want to print  titles in html with underlined n-th letter , where n is "underlinedkey"

My html :

```
<div class="titleCont">
    <div ng-repeat="title in titleObject">{{title.title}}</div>  
</div>
```

Output I am getting :

> Title1
>
> Sub-Heading
>
> Heading text
>
> Some Title
>
> More Title

What my requirement is :

> T̲itle1
>
> Su̲b-Heading
>
> Hea̲ding text
>
> So̲me Title
>
> Mor̲e Title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a directive can be:

```
.directive('underline', function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      underline: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, element){
       var html = scope.underline.title.replace(new RegExp("(" + scope.underline.underlinekey +")"), "<u>$1</u>");
       element.html(html)
    }
  }
})
```

```
<div ng-repeat="title in titleObject">
  <div underline="title"></div>
</div>
```

**[Demo 1](http://plnkr.co/edit/crw8NzbpznWoNFUAyA7w?p=preview)**

**[Demo 2](http://plnkr.co/edit/w5FooYLJscvtViq2K8PF?p=preview)** *with attributes*

Comment: I like this solution.  I would recommend attributes for the entry and the replacement since this would all you to use the directive without a specific object definition.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Good point, in which case you would recommend, two attributes or just to key?, `title` as an attribute or `.text()`?

Comment: Two attributes makes the most sense to me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind html with [`ng-bind-html`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) you have to run it through [`$sce.trustAsHtml`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsHtml) first. Other than that, you can just generate the HTML with string replacement in the usual way.

```
<div ng-repeat="title in ::titleObject" ng-bind-html=underlineTitle(title)>

$scope.underlineTitle = function (title) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(
        title.title.replace(
            title.underlinekey,
            "<u>" + title.underlinekey + "</u>"
        )
    );
};
```

Make sure you only do tihs with HTML you trust / are actually generating.

http://plnkr.co/edit/0pFGjaKYxN87TvQZbw6l?p=preview